# Bulk Update Multiple Records

Tags: laravel, bulkupdate

I have a problem that has been bothering me for weeks and I hope to get some help.

I have two tables containing transactions (customer, amount, currency, transaction_id and status). The first one contains data with up-to-date status. What I want to do is to be able to mass update the data with the status of the table_2 having the same reference as the table_1.

My Controller

```
​
$table_1 = Table_1::select('status','transaction_id')->get();
$table_2 = Table_2::select('status','transaction_id')->get();

foreach ($table_1 as $key => $value) {
        $reference = $value->transaction_id;
        $status = $value->status;
        Table_2::where('transaction_id', $reference)->update(['status' => $status]);
}

​
```

Only one transaction is updated while I want it to update all the status transactions. I repeat that the status of the transactions are different from each other

Because each transaction has a unique reference. If the reference is the same, take the status of table_1 and update it in table_2

Comment: Can you check your question above, I think something is missing. I can't see where are you updating the record in `table_2`.

Comment: ```

$table_1 = Table_1::select('status','transaction_id')->get();
$table_2 = Table_2::select('status','transaction_id')->get();
foreach ($table_1 as $key => $value) {
  $reference = $value->transaction_id;
        $status = $value->status;
  Table_2::where('transaction_id', $reference)->update(['status' => $status]);
}

```